# updating a chart in chart.JS using a dropdown button

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chart.Js to render charts in an application.
What I am looking for is to give the user to be able to compare two dataset using a dropdown button.

I tried to edit something I found but I can manage to make it work. 
I tried that code :

```
 document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var newDataset = {
        label: 'Dataset ' + config.data.datasets.length,
        backgroundColor: "black",
        borderColor: "black",
        data: [],
        fill: false
      };
      for (var index = 0; index < config.data.labels.length; ++index) {
        newDataset.data.push(randomScalingFactor());
      }
      config.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
      window.myLine.update();
    });
```

I created a JSfiddle with all the code to give you an overview: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ben2pop/219hry2s/36/

Answer (score -1):

You need to place the ID `test` on the select box and not the option.
Change

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function() {
```

To

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
```

now you can access the value of the change by `e.target.val` and decide what data you want to insert / remove based on the user interaction.